# how can I remove javascript and CSS inside wordpress posts after migration from blogger to wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I migrated a blog from blogger to wordpress, but blogger had CSS and Javascript pieces in the post description, which now got migrated into the wordpress post.

As I have 300 posts, I am looking for a bulk method to delete. 
I tried Phpmyadmin replacement but the escaping of the special characters did not work.

https://onlycrumbsremain.co.uk/2018/07/strawberry-cupcakes.html

you can see at the bottom of the recipe card the CSS and at the bottom of the post the Google Analytic javascript.

I tried a search and replace plugin, but they did only have a one line entry field , and I think the line breaks make it not work.

So the question is, how can I remove that from the posts in bulk ?
How can I write an SQL command that takes care of the different special characters?

Thanks for your help. 
Sabrina

Comment: Export all the post and do bulk replace using any editor after replacing everything re-import all post data after removing JS & CSS. Take database backup before uploading any changes

https://www.wikihow.com/Export-and-Import-a-Wordpress-Blog

Comment: Excellent. I used the sql import/export via phpmysql but it was working the same. Thanks for this great idea!